# how to change shape color using `simple_kml` in python

Tags: python, kml, simplekml

I'm using `simple_kml` library to generate a kml file with data sent from `drawing manager` on google Maps using Javascript, everything goes fine except the color of the shape .. the color send in this format `#ec0909`, and here is how am trying to add it to the shape:

```py
ls = kml.newlinestring(name="Polyline")
ls.coords = [(latlng['lng'], latlng['lat']) for latlng in shape['coordinates']]
ls.description = shape['info_box']
print(f"THE COLOR IS {color_code}") #returns #ec0909
ls.style.polystyle.color = color_code
```

as you see the color should be red .. but it is shown as blue/red shaded color.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`color_code` needs to not contain the pound sign character; your comment makes it seem like that string is `#ec0909` but it needs to be `ec0909`. Beyond that, you’re working on a `kml.LineString` object and not a `kml.Polygon` object, so I think you need to set the color using `ls.style.linestyle.color` instead of `ls.style.polystyle.color`.

Hope that helps,

—K

**EDIT:** see more [here](https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styling.html#styling-a-linestring) and consider you may need to convert a hex string using `kml.Color.hex()` in your assignment, or include alpha codes to make `color_code` into the string `ec0909ff`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is expecting a KML color code, then not only do you need to remove the # sign and add alpha/opacity, you also need to reverse the 3 colors.

KML does not use "normal" color order (RGB), instead it is in reversed order of Blue, Green, Red, with alpha/opacity in the front, for: AABBGGRR, where AA is alpha, BB is blue, GG is Green and RR is Red.

For more info see the documentation for the `<color>` tag, here:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#elements-specific-to-colorstyle

specifically this line:

```
The order of expression is aabbggrr
```

For the color you indicated, the KML will need to end up containing: `ff0909ec`.

That said, it looks like simple_kml can take color codes in a number of formats depending on which method you use, so pick the right one in the docs: https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/constants.html#color